# HTMLAgilityPack and XPath Target

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Tournament Name</a>
            <br /> Tournament Address </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a>View Available Space and Book Online</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <em>Event Cost:</em> $$$
        </td>

        <td> Date and Time </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>
            <p>
                <strong>
                    <img title="Boy's Teams can enter this tournament" />
                    <img  title="Girl's Teams can not enter this tournament" />
                    <img  title="Disabled Teams can not enter this tournament" />
                </strong>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td>
            TimeFrame
        </td>

    </tr>

     <tr>
       <td>
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image.gif" />
            <img src="image...." />
            <img src="image...." />
            <img src="image...." />
            <img src="image...." />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(This table is repeated many times on the page).

I'm trying to extract the **Tournament Name.**

I have the following C# code:

```
namespace AcademyScraper
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string url = "http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp";
            var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = Webget.Load(url);

            var root = doc.DocumentNode;
            var nodes = root.Descendants();

            HtmlNodeCollection tableCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='infobox']/table");

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < tableCollection.Count(); i++)
            {
            HtmlNode tournamentName = tableCollection[i].SelectSingleNode("/tr[1]/td/a");

            MessageBox.Show(tournamentName.InnerText);
            // I get an exception here

            }

        }


    }
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that no matter what I try I can't seem to target the  tag containing the tournament name. If I do `MessageBox.Show(tableCollection[i].OuterHTML);`, the table contents will be rendered fine inside the messagebox with no problems. However, I get a reference exception whenever I try to get the tournamentName. Based on the HTML I think it should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this (i created a console app to try):

```
 private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string url = "http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp";
        var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = Webget.Load(url);
        var aTags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[1]/a");

        foreach (var tag in aTags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerText);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following XPath seems to work fine for me :**

```
//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[br]/a
```

**Console application demo :**

```
string url = "http://www.reddishvulcans.com/uk_tournament_database.asp";
var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = Webget.Load(url);

//print top 10 result just for the sake of demo
var result = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//div[@class='infobox']/table/tr/td[br]/a")
                .Take(10);
foreach (HtmlNode node in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

**output :**

```
The North West Junior Champions League 2016
PLAY AT CHELSEA - STAMFORD BRIDGE FOOTBALL TOURNAMENT 2016
PLAY AT FC BARCELONA -  CAMP NOU FOOTBALL TOUR 2016 - THE EUROPA CUP
Silverdale Soccersevens XIX
NORTH HALIFAX MINI SOCCER TOURNAMENT 2016
Halton & District JFL Mini Soccer Tournament
Colwyn Bay FC Junior Tournament
GMCJFC Pat Mangan Festival of Football 2016
Fred England Trophy
Fred England Trophy
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a task work with network `var doc = Webget.Load(url);` it can make some times, but you got it in `main thread` -> conflict. You need run network task in other thread. NOTE `MessageBox.Show(tournamentName.InnerText);` is UI thread(main thread) you should run it in `INVOKE` delegate.